# Mudautocomplete issue

Tags: mudblazor

I have a Mudautocomplete that is working, my only problem is when selecting an item in the dropdown.
When I type, my SearchFunc filters the result as it should.
But when I select an item, the SearchFunc is not fired. Meaning that my filter contains more items then just the selected item.

How can I solve this to only get the selected item?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using the bind-value property.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).